# Do I need I94 for re-entry to US by Car if I have travelled by air before with valid e-I94?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, paperwork, i-94

I recently travelled to US from Canada by air (I am Canadian PR holder with multi entry B1/B2 visa). I could see the I94 online (as I travelled by air) and it has an admit until date for 6 months.

I have to travel back to US by car this time. Do I need a new I94 at land border or I can print online I94 and re-use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need to print your I-94 - you'll be admitted to "continue" your originally granted stay, which is also electronically recorded.

Comment: Minor correction: you don't even need a passport stamp (a colleague of mine didn't get one when entering by train). They'll see the I-94 when they scan your passport.